# Unable to Install Meteor: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to install [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) on my Windows 7 PC using the Windows Installer. Every time I try, it downloads for a while and then a window opens saying that the "Setup Failed". The log file contains the following lines that I think are relevant.

> [121C:04D0][2015-10-02T09:38:56]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
>   [121C:04D0][2015-10-02T09:38:56]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-user MSI package.
>   [121C:04D0][2015-10-02T09:38:56]i319: Applied execute package: SetupMeteor_UserInstall, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
>   [121C:04D0][2015-10-02T09:38:56]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.

I believe that this problem is to do with my computer and not the installer, but I am unsure why these errors occur or what I should try in order to fix them.

Comment: I am also having same problem. Have you found any solutions, that you can also help me with?

Comment: I managed to do it when I switched from my school network to my home network. It might have something to do with either the speed of the network or the restrictions it has.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to cancel the installation and then re-executed it with the administrator privilege. It worked but also took hours to complete (maybe by my internet connection quality).

Here is [an alternative way to install on Windows](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/version-NEXT/long-form/alternate-windows-installation.md).